# How to find records from array object based on values of another array in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Lets say we have an array containing ids of objects that need to be fetched

This is the ids that need to fetched from another object array

```
`idvalues=[2,3]`
```

This is the object array

```
 array_object=[#<CustomPricing id: 2, base_price: 500>, #<CustomPricing id: 3, base_price: 700>, #<CustomPricing id: 4, base_price: 900>, #<CustomPricing id: 2, base_price: 500>]
```

How can we fetch objects with the `id's` `2` & `3` and put them in new array. Here also there are multiple records with same id so just want the first record only.

I tried like this

```
events = idvalues.each {|id_value| array_object.find(id=id_value)}
```

but this returned the `idvalue` itself which is `[2,3]`. How can we achieve this?

Comment: `idvalues.map` instead of `each`

Comment: @engineersmnky tried that before but that returns all ids with `2 and 3`. I just want the first record for each ids. Also if I try  `array_object.find(id=id_value).first` it returns just 2 object with same id

Comment: sorry you need to change `find` to `find {|cp| cp.id == id_value}` not even sure how this is working for you right now if `array_object` is actually an `Array`

Comment: `idvalues.map {|id| array_object.find { |o| o.id == id} }`

Comment: where are these values coming from as it seems like the database would be the best place to handle this e.g. `CustomPrice.distinct.where(id: idvalues)`

Comment: @engineersmnky These are not real database fields. These are from recurring event rules. An event can span multiple days. I am now figuring out a way to fetch pricing based on the overlapping of events(like full overlapping, partial and so on). So will pick a pricing based on the overlapping. Almost done with all those then I encountered this. Actually can store event itself instead of ids and thats a workaround as no need to do these mapping again. But was curious on how to make this work and thought could be just a simple `map` or `each` thing... :) Thank you for the support

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution would be:

```
grouped = array_object.group_by(&:id)
selected = idvalues.uniq.map { |id| grouped[id].first }
```

(the uniq can be removed if the idvalues array does not contain any duplicates)

Or another version

```
selected = array_object.group_by(&:id).values_at(*id_values).map(&:first)
```

(see comment by @mudasobwa to this answer)

This first groups the pricings by `id` and then uses `map` to find a mapping of ids to a the first pricing with that ID.

But the comment to your question by @mudasobwa shows a easier way to solve this:

```
selected = idvalues.map {|id| array_object.find { |o| o.id == id} }
```

Question remaining: why does `array_object` even contains duplicate pricings?

If they were unique you could just use select:

```
selected = array_object.select { |pricing| idvalues.includes?(pricing.id) }
```

You could make the array uniq first:

```
selected = array_object.select { |pricing| idvalues.includes?(pricing.id) }
```

(if the objects in the array have a proper equality operator implemented)

But honestly I think the array should not contain duplicate items in the first place. This sounds like a Query that could be optimized?

Comment: `array_object.group_by(&:id).values_at(*id_values).map(&:first)`

Comment: Easier, but slower :) `group_by` seems to be a proper way to go.

Comment: @engineersmnky yes its still returning same ids

Comment: @Abhilash no, it won't (unless the idvalues array has duplicate ids, which according to the question is not the case - the pricings are duplicate)

Comment: @pascalbetz contains duplicate as I generated it using icecube recurring. As there is no database record for that I put same ids to easily reference back to the event.

Comment: @pascalbetz that `uniq` wont work here as I have another date value which is different in each event. I removed that and some other fields from op as to make the question simpler. :)..Sorry for the confusion caused though..

Comment: @Abhilash making the "question simpler" can make it harder to help please clarify the problem in your question because as of right now all of these alternative approaches are valid

Comment: I'm sure you'll find a answer that works for you :-)

Comment: @pascalbetz Thank you for the support. Still didn't fix my problem but this answers the op also got an idea on how to approach this kind of problem.. I will have a better look at this tomorrow. Now simply can't think any further. :)

Comment: I considered `array_object.uniq(&:id).select { |o| idvalues.include?(o) }`.  While [Enumerable#uniq](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-uniq) is guaranteed to be order-preserving, [Array#select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-select) evidently is not. I therefore could not be certain that now or in future this would return the first element in `array_object` with `:id` having a given value in `idvalues`. (cont.)

Comment: ...Similarly, the doc for [Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) does not guarantee the order of the elements in each value of the hash returned. One would expect both of these methods would return values whose order is consistent with their order in `array_object`, but we must of course be certain of that. It may be that the specs for these methods contain an ordering test, but I am reluctant to make assumptions beyond the official doc for the method.

Comment: @pascalbetz both `selected = idvalues.map {|id| array_object.find { |o| o.id == id} }` and  `selected =array_object.group_by(&:id).values_at(*id_values).map(&:first)` working for me. Which one could be more efficient?

Comment: Abhilash, if `n = array_object.size` and `m = id_values.size`, computational efficiency is `O(n*m)` for the former and `O(n+m)` for the latter. That is, the problem with the former is that part of `array_object` must be traversed for each element of `id_values`. As I explained in my comments, however, the use of `group_by` does not appear to guarantee the production of a correct solution.

Comment: @CarySwoveland  Thank you for the time in explaining this. Have a better understanding now.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to extract the desired instances from `array_object` that is intended to be relatively efficient.

**Code**

```
require 'set'

def extract(array_object, id_values)
  idv = id_values.to_set
  arr = []
  array_object.each do |obj|
    id = obj[:id]
    if idv.include?(id)
      arr << obj
      idv.delete(id)
    end
    break if idv.empty?
  end 
  idv.empty? ? arr : nil
end
```

**Example**

```
id_values = [2, 3]

CustomPricing = Struct.new(:id, :base_price) {}
array_object = [[3, 700], [2, 500], [4, 900], [2, 500]].map do |id, bp|
  CustomPricing.new(id, bp)
end
  #=> [#<struct CustomPricing id=3, base_price=700>,
  #    #<struct CustomPricing id=2, base_price=500>,
  #    #<struct CustomPricing id=4, base_price=900>,
  #    #<struct CustomPricing id=2, base_price=500>]
```

Readers unfamiliar with structs (or needing a brush-up) may wish to read [this article](https://www.leighhalliday.com/ruby-struct).

```
extract(array_object, id_values)
  #=> [#<struct CustomPricing id=3, base_price=700>,
  #    #<struct CustomPricing id=2, base_price=500>]
```

If the objects are to ordered by the values of `:id` that reflect their order in `id_values`, the penultimate line (`idv.empty? ? arr : nil`) can be replaced by the following.

```
idv.empty? ? arr.sort_by { |obj| id_values.index(obj[:id]) } : nil
```

which produces the following return value.

```
[#<struct CustomPricing id=2, base_price=500>,
 #<struct CustomPricing id=3, base_price=700>]
```

Comment: Thank you will have a look at this. In the accepted answer both `selected = idvalues.map {|id| array_object.find { |o| o.id == id} }` and  `selected =array_object.group_by(&:id).values_at(*id_values).map(&:first)`  works for me. Is this approach more efficient than these?